# How to modify java bytecode after compilation using compiler plugins?

Tags: java, javac, bytecode, java-compiler-api

I want to modify some java classes bytecode during/after compilation phase, but before packaging, in order to use custom `invokedynamic` bootstrap methods.

In order to do so, I have written a Java compiler plugin using the `jdk.compiler` module, extending `com.sun.source.util.Plugin`, and attached a listener that executes after bytecode generation phase, however, the `jdk.compiler` module's public API does not exposes any method or with reference to the bytecode stream or generated `.class` file.

Are there any other strategies I could follow?

So far, the code looks like this:

```java
package plugin;

import com.sun.source.util.JavacTask;
import com.sun.source.util.Plugin;
import com.sun.source.util.TaskEvent;
import com.sun.source.util.TaskListener;

public class Main implements Plugin, TaskListener {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "my-plugin";
    }

    @Override
    public void init(JavacTask task, String... args) {
        task.addTaskListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void finished(TaskEvent e) {
        if(TaskEvent.Kind.GENERATE.equals(e.getKind())){
            System.out.println("no byte code reference here :(");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean autoStart() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why?  Please explain your use case.

Comment: I'd like to use a different Lambda bootstrap method instead of the default `LambdaMetafactory` implementation that the compiler sticks to the compiled class file.

Comment: Seems like this has not been foreseen. Only the initiator of the compilation who either, invokes `JavacTask`’s `generate()` method or provides the `JavaFileManager` in the first place, has access to the generated class files.